# React parent component check if child will render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that depending on some of its props will end up rendering something or not. The render function of the children looks something like this:

```
render() {
  if (props.a == 'foo' && props.b == 'bar') {
    return (<p> Hey There </p>);
  } else if {props.a == 'z') {
    return (<p> Hey There </p>);
  } // more conditions
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
```

In the parent component I am rendering several child components, and I need to know how many of them will render, because depending on that number I will do something or not. I don't want to repeat the conditional logic from the child to the parent, but I don't know how from a parent I can find out if the children will render or not.

Comment: If a parent renders, all children will render unless some of them have implemented shouldcomponentUpdate which returns false or if they the PureComponent in which case a shallow comparison is done between state and props for them

Comment: `The render function looks something like this` , render function of what , child or parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with [perpetualjourney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809281/3231537)'s answer, I thought I could give you a possibility of counting the children.

The easiest would be to save the rendering of the children first to a variable and then to render that result.

```
var kids = this.props.items.map( (k, i) => <Kid condition={k} key={i} /> );
var totalKids = kids.reduce( (k, i) => k + (i.type( i.props ) ? 1 : 0), 0);
```

Now, this will render your children twice, so it is not the best when you already have a performance heavy method

```js
const Kid = ({ condition }) => condition % 3 === 0 ? <h1>{ condition }</h1> : null;

class ConditionalKids extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var kids = this.props.items.map( (k, i) => <Kid condition={k} key={i} /> );
    var totalKids = kids.reduce( (k, i) => k + (i.type( i.props ) ? 1 : 0), 0);
    return <div>
      <p>Rendered in total { totalKids }</p>
      { kids }
    </div>;
  }
}

const items = [...new Array(5)].map( i => parseInt( Math.random() * 10 ) );
console.log( items );

const target = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render( <ConditionalKids items={items} />, target );
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Icepickle, this is not working for me. Are you sure that:
```var kids = this.props.items.map( (k, i) => <Kid condition={k} key={i} /> );``` renders the kids? It doesn't for me, it just initializes the components, but it doesn't render. It renders them when I do `{kids}`. I have put a console logs in the render method of the kid, and I don't see it twice.

Comment: @HommerSmith It does, but not at the time of mapping, it will during the reduce and the actual render

Comment: Why would it do it in the reduce? What are you doing in the reduce that is making it render? Is it because you call i.props? Or...?

Comment: @HommerSmith It's because of the call to `i.type( i.props )` which will call the presentational component so we can see what is the output of it

Comment: Oh, gotcha. How did you know this? What is exactly, the `i.type` or the `i.props`?

Comment: @HommerSmith Oh I had to iterate the children once or twice before to try some things out :)

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is a bit of an anti-pattern in React.
If I understand your question, the children render output would influence their parent's render ouptput, which is likely to get you stuck in a render loop.

I suggest you keep the children components as simple as possible and hoist the conditional logic to the parent which will allow you to count how many children you'll be rendering in place.

Please let me know if I got your question wrong.

Comment: But that logic is specific to the children.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this problem is to use `state`.

In this [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko6x6ly3w5), I use the `if/else` logic to update the component's `state`. This is done inside the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

Your `render` method is simplified to a `switch` statement.

If you want to call an imperative API based on the `if/else` logic you have, you can do that inside your `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. This is also simplified to a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very pertinent question that affects applications of any complexity. Unfortunately there's no clear way to model this using React today. I've done a ton of React and would recommend what @perpetualjourney said: hoist the logic to a common parent. Sometimes you'll need to move it way up, but do it instead of messing around with `React.Children.map` or `React.Context` since they'd create dependency between the components and would make it harder for you to move them around if needed.

```js
const hasA = computeHasA({ ... });
const hasB = computeHasB({ ... });
const hasAny = hasA || hasB;

if (hasAny) {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      {hasA && <Tab title="A">Some content</Tab>}
      {hasB && <Tab title="B">Another content</Tab>}
    </Tabs>

  );
}
```

When you really can't move to logic upwards, for example, if the children do network requests, which is probably an edge-case, I'd recommend passing a prop used to report whether they have content or not and storing it into the parent's state:

```js
const [numberOfRenderedChildren, setNumberOfRenderedChildren] = useState(0);

const incrementNumberOfRenderedChildren = () => {
  // Use a callback to prevent race conditions
  setNumberOfRenderedChildren(prevValue => prevValue + 1);
};


return (
  <MyContainer isVisible={numberOfRenderedChildren > 0}>
    {items.map(item => (
      <ComplexChild
        key={item.id}
        // Avoid spreading props like ...item. It breaks semantics
        item={item}
        reportHasContent={incrementNumberOfRenderedChildren}
      />
    )}
  </MyContainer>
);
```

It could get more complex if you need loaders and error messages, but then I'd fire all the requests in the parent. Try to keep it simple, easy to read, even if it means more verbosity. You won't regret when you need to come back to those files a few weeks later.